# Read file content and query data. python 3.5.1

Tags: python

I am attempting to query a sales record that I have saved in a `data.txt` file. Each line is separated by commas:

`<date>,<branch_name>,<total_daily_sale>,<number_of_daily_transactions>`

this is the information in the data.txt file.

```
1-2-2014,Frankton,42305.67,23
12-4-2014,Glenview,21922.22,17
10-2-2015,Glenview,63277.9,32
10-5-2015,Glenview,83290.09,16
11-6-2015,Frankton,81301.82,34
10-10-2015,Frankton,62333.3,40
11-11-2015,Frankton,28998.8,29
1-1-2016,Glenview,51083.5,27
1-3-2016,Glenview,62155.72,42
27-3-2016,Frankton,33075.1,18
2-4-2016,Glenview,61824.7,35
```

I wanted to write a value-returning function `readdata(filename)` and also write a non-value-returning funtion `print_all_records(records)` to format the template and display it like the below screenshot in blue:

[image]

Also below is the code I had help with that utilises SQLite data. But I'm hoping there's another way other than using SQLite.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE data
         (field1 text, field2 text)''')

data = open('data.txt')
items1 = []
items2 = []
items3 = []
data2 = open('outs.txt')

for item in data:
try:
    (item1,item2) = item.strip().split(',',1)

    items1.append('item1')
    items2.append('item2')
    c.execute("insert into data (field1,field2) values (?,?)",
        (item1,item2))
    conn.commit()    

except:
    pass

conn.close()

print ('All item successfully stored in database')
```

Comment: Please do not use images for text.

Comment: The lines/rows are separated by newlines, the columns are separated by commas :).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt",header=None,sep=",")
df.columns = ["Date","Branch","Sale","Transaction"]
print(df)
```

output

```
Index Date      Branch   Sale     Transaction    
0     1-2-2014  Frankton 42305.67 23    
1     12-4-2014 Glenview 21922.22 17    
...
```